# Is this a valid proof that function composition is associative in type theory?

Tags: functions, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

On page 56 of "Homotopy Type Theory" they give the first exercise of defining function composition and proving that it is a associative. So here goes:
$$\circ :\Pi_{g:A\rightarrow B}\Pi_{f:B\rightarrow C}(A\rightarrow C)$$
$\circ$ is a function that takes in two functions and returns another, we will naturally use it as infix and define
$$(f\circ g) (a):=f(g(a))$$
where $a:A$. Now let $h:Z\rightarrow A$, and let $z:Z$ and $a:=h(z)$ then 
$$(f\circ g) (a) := (f\circ g)h(z):=f(g(h(z)))$$
$(f\circ (g\circ h))(z)$ is the application of $f$ to $(g\circ h)(z)$, since $g\circ h$ is $\lambda z.g(h(z))$ we should just be able to apply f then just apply the entire thing to $z$. But this doesn't seem right in the framework of propositions as types. I feel like I'm meant to prove that you can construct an element of the type $(f\circ g)\circ h = f \circ (g\circ h)$. Despite having read the first chapter, I'm not quite sure about how to go about this, hints would be appreciated and please let me know at the top of your post if you intend on giving the full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a mash. So first, given a $z$, $((f \circ g) \circ h)(z)$ and $(f \circ (g \circ h))(z)$ are simply equal.  We say that they are judgementally or definitionally equal. (Usually this can be checked by computing to normal form and verifying that you get the same normal form which is effectively what you did. This is generally a highly mechanical process.) In a proof assistant like Coq or Agda, there is no work to do(; it automatically does the computation).   The proof term for the corresponding identity type is $\mathtt{refl}$.  So, to this extent, you're not missing anything.

**Correction**: As Mike Shulman points out, when the pointwise equality is judgemental, function extensionality *isn't* necessary. So there really is nothing to do but the mechanical exercise of checking whether the two terms have the same normal form. If you want to completely "show your work", you can list out the [reductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction). I'll leave the following paragraph which is incorrect in stating that function extensionality is necessary, but highlights function extensionality which is a thing you need to be a bit more mindful of in intensional type theories in general and even in HoTT which has it propositionally.

> But, this is not the same as saying $(f \circ g) \circ h = f \circ (g
>  \circ h)$ as *this* requires function extensionality given the above
>   fact.  Function extensionality typically *doesn't* hold in intensional
>   type theories, and it certainly doesn't hold definitionally, but it
>   does hold propositionally in HoTT.  Basically, your proof is a proof
>   of $$\prod_{z:Z}((f \circ g) \circ h)(z) =_Z (f \circ (g \circ
>  h))(z)$$ via $\lambda z:Z.\mathtt{refl}(z)$ and by applying function
>   extensionality you can produce a term of type $(f \circ g) \circ h
>  =_{Z\to C} f \circ (g \circ h)$. The proof term would then be something like $\mathtt{funext}(\lambda z:Z.\mathtt{refl}(z))$ though
>   you definitely need to provide some additional arguments to
>   $\mathtt{funext}$ to actually make this a statement about
>   associativity of composition.

Comment: Do you know if this is all they were looking for in the exercise? Also, some of your notation is foreign to me which might be because I haven't gotten far enough in the book. How do I read $\Pi:Z.$ and $\lambda z:Z.refl(z)$?

Comment: I switched the answer to use a notation consistent with the question for the dependent product type. The latter is just a typed variant of [lambda notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Notation). The above link also explains the convention I was using for the dependent product, which, personally, I use universally.

Comment: It's true that *in general*, a proof of a pointwise equality doesn't imply an equality between functions without funext.  However, since in this case the pointwise equality is *judgmental*, the functions are also judgmentally equal.  That is, both $(f\circ h) \circ h$ and $f\circ (g\circ h)$ are judgmentally equal to $\lambda x. f(g(h(x)))$, and hence to each other.  (You can check this in Coq or Agda.)  So we don't actually need funext here... which is good since the HoTT book doesn't introduce it until chapter 2!

Comment: @MikeShulman I briefly wondered about this.  I should have checked in Agda, so thanks for calling me out. In fact, in thinking about this now, it should have been embarrassingly obvious to me simply because $\eta$-*long* $\beta$-normal form is often the used normal form.

Comment: FWIW, we don't actually need judgmental $\eta$-conversion for this, only $\beta$-reduction.  (We do need judgmental $\eta$-conversion to conclude that function composition is judgmentally *unital*, however.)